# Plot multiple "columns" with VEGA-LITE and include a legend

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following minimal data:

```js
[
    {"date": "2019-01-01", "foo": 10000, "bar": 10, "goo": 30},
    {"date": "2019-01-02", "foo": 30000, "bar": 20, "goo": 20},
    {"date": "2019-01-03", "foo": 40000, "bar": 20, "goo": 10},
    {"date": "2019-01-04", "foo": 1000,  "bar": 60, "goo": 20}
]
```

Which I plot using VEGA-LITE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Embedding Vega-Lite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.4.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@3.3.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@4.2.0"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var yourVlSpec = {
            "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
            "Title": "Insights stats",
            "description": "Overview of insights stats",
            "width": 1000,
            "height": 450,
            "data": {
                "url": "./data.json"
            },
            "layer": [
                {
                    "mark": "line",
                    "encoding": {
                        "x": {
                            "field": "date",
                            "type": "temporal",
                            "title": "Date"
                        },
                        "y": {
                            "field": "foo",
                            "type": "quantitative",
                            "title": "Some Foo"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "mark": {
                        "type": "line",
                        "stroke": "firebrick"
                    },
                    "encoding": {
                        "x": {
                            "field": "date",
                            "type": "temporal"
                        },
                        "y": {
                            "field": "bar",
                            "type": "quantitative",
                            "title": null,
                            "scale": { "domain": [0, 100] }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "mark": {
                        "type": "line",
                        "stroke": "red"
                    },
                    "encoding": {
                        "x": {
                            "field": "date",
                            "type": "temporal"
                        },
                        "y": {
                            "field": "goo",
                            "type": "quantitative",
                            "title": "Ratio (%)",
                            "scale": { "domain": [0, 100] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "resolve": { "scale": { "y": "independent" } }
        };
        vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I fail to have a proper legend for each line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vega-Lite will generate a legend for a chart if there is an encoding that warrants it, such as color, shape, etc.

In the case of plotting multiple columns, a useful pattern is to use the [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) in order to specify your colors via an encoding rather than by manual layering. The result looks something like this ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgAVZmOTYoASSWxG1fLDCw86PLDUbIAE2QIATo0J4eKnJADyVK4UjMgA7mDcAGZgjMam5pbWtvYQkKGMjiz6AIwADPnqqSjxePoALACsuYVQjjaYOKAQqRToYqwu+gDaGs1gwE42er4ATLnZAJwi49PZalCR3Nw51VDs6K4rqlDUS-rSuQC+NX0DdXjDUGOTs9Mj85CLyzgH25Drmzhjb7vPYGPHXrNM5DfSQa5TGa5aQPJ7lVbvDb6b47PY4PKAvoQEEXMEQ265MqwtFgbJvD76ABsCN+yKOQIAuhpMVA8K50MZFq5UN0gQNFmJHN1HntyUifnsGYcNAyapAMK4ANZgiRKPRy5BKeDcRyxaj6JrNSAADwNjxCgrB53VrIAnoRLpALqhCNx2WJICzUrazZELULfK12janfbHQBHVgcrxJRhUT0nKDasRu33+sGK5A+t54MNgpTcVCxNqe5kgQ5AA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "title": "Insights stats",
  "description": "Overview of insights stats",
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 450,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2019-01-01", "foo": 10, "bar": 10, "goo": 30},
      {"date": "2019-01-02", "foo": 30, "bar": 20, "goo": 20},
      {"date": "2019-01-03", "foo": 40, "bar": 20, "goo": 10},
      {"date": "2019-01-04", "foo": 1, "bar": 60, "goo": 20}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["foo", "bar", "goo"]}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation! For those who wonders how to change the Legends name from "key" to something else, all you need to do it to add `"title": "the title you want",`.

Comment: Important question: If we have different marks, say a line and a point, how we include them in the legends? Currently, it only takes one or the other, but not both!